# Solve the equation in the following question

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Solve the equation $$\sqrt{x+1}+\sqrt{2-x}+2=x^2+2x$$

I tried with squaring both sides, but I got confused, any help will be thankful.

Comment: Why does this have the abstract-algebra tag?

Comment: @SamirKhan Sorry didn't see it clear